# What are the Tomcat Component? What is Catalina and Coyote?

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

Can anyone describe

- What is component in Tomcat and what is role of it in Tomcat server?
- What is Coyote?
- What is Catalina?

Comment: **Tomcat** - is a web server, which is having the following components: - Catalina - Servlet container name - Jasper - JSP engine - Coyote - HTTP connector - Cluster - is load balancer to manage large scale application.

Comment: This question is not particularly broad, apart from the first point which is a bit confusing. The second two can be comfortably answered in a couple of sentences each.

Comment: Gotta go with GhostCat on this one. The fact that this question can be answered in a single wikipedia link suggests one should have tried there (or similar) first. If one didn't understand something there, *that* would be a useful question.

Answer (score 59):

**Catalina** is Tomcat's servlet container. Catalina implements Sun Microsystems' specifications for servlet and JavaServer Pages (JSP). In Tomcat, a Realm element represents a "database" of usernames, passwords, and roles (similar to Unix groups) assigned to those users. Different implementations of Realm allow Catalina to be integrated into environments where such authentication information is already being created and maintained, and then use that information to implement Container Managed Security as described in the Servlet Specification

**Coyote** is a Connector component for Tomcat that supports the HTTP 1.1 protocol as a web server. This allows Catalina, nominally a Java Servlet or JSP container, to also act as a plain web server that serves local files as HTTP documents.

**Coyote** listens for incoming connections to the server on a specific TCP port and forwards the request to the Tomcat Engine to process the request and send back a response to the requesting client. Another Coyote Connector, Coyote JK, listens similarly but instead forwards its requests to another web server, such as Apache, using the JK protocol. This usually offers better performance.