# What is the Coyote framework and where can I read more about it?

Tags: coyote

I have recently heard about a new framework called Coyote.

Where can I read more about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the Tomcat Component? What is Catalina and Coyote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985051/what-are-the-tomcat-component-what-is-catalina-and-coyote)

Comment: @rkosegi, The Coyote open source system is now released. For more information see the [coyote] tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coyote/info and the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggressive shipping deadlines make it challenging to develop bug-free software. Researchers at Microsoft created Coyote, an open-source .NET framework and intelligent testing tool that helps developers build asynchronous systems quickly and confidently:

See [Microsoft Research Coyote Project](https://aka.ms/AA7unru).